# Code compiled with no error but moving empty object to new list

Tags: angularjs

```
        <!--After loading no error from inspection but the move method not responding-->
        <!--The HTML--->
        <!doctype html>
        <html ng-app='ShoppingListCheckOff'>
        <html lang="en">
          <head>
            <title>Shopping List Check Off</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="app.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
            <style>
              .emptyMessage {
                font-weight: bold;
                color: red;
                font-size: 1.2em;
              }
              li {
                margin-bottom: 7px;
                font-size: 1.2em;
              }
              li > button {
                margin-left: 6px;
              }
              button > span {
                color: green;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
        <body>
          <div class="container">
          <h1>Shopping List Check Off</h1>

          <div class="row">
           <!--i think all is ok with this div as everything loaded as i wanted it-->
        <!--the ng-hide worked also--> 
            <!--To Buy List -->
            <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller='ToBuyController as itemAdder'>
             <h2>To Buy:</h2>

             <ul>
               <li ng-repeat="item in itemAdder.shoppingList2">Name: {{item.name}} , Quantity: {{item.quantity}}
                 <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="itemAdder.move()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Bought</button></li>
             </ul> 

             <div ng-hide="itemAdder.shoppingList2.length" class="emptyMessage">Everything is bought!</div>
            </div>
        <!--I want to move the displayed items to this div on click of the bought button-->
        <!--ng-hide i think it worked-->
            <!-- Already Bought List -->
            <div class="col-md-6" ng-controller='AlreadyBoughtController as boughtItem'>
             <h2>Already Bought:</h2>
             <ul>
               <li>Bought <span ng-bind="boughtItem.boughtList.length"></span> 10 cookies</li>

               <li ng-repeat="item in boughtItem.boughtList">Name: {{item.name}} , Quantity: {{item.quantity}}</li>
             </ul>
              <div ng-hide="boughtItem.boughtList.length" class="emptyMessage">Nothing bought yet.</div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        </body>
        </html>

                               <!--Script-->
        (function () {
        'use strict';


        angular.module('ShoppingListCheckOff', [])
        .controller('ToBuyController', ToBuyController)
        .controller('AlreadyBoughtController', AlreadyBoughtController)
        .service('ShoppingListService', ShoppingListService);

         <!--This part populated with the buttons ready to be clicked-->
        ToBuyController.$inject = ['ShoppingListService'];
        function ToBuyController(ShoppingListService) {
          var itemAdder = this;
          itemAdder.shoppingList2 = ShoppingListService.shoppingList2;
        }

on click of the button i was expecting the item clicked to move to here

AlreadyBoughtController.$inject = ['ShoppingListService'];
        function AlreadyBoughtController(ShoppingListService) {
         var boughtItem= this;
          boughtItem.boughtList= ShoppingListService.bought;
        }
```

Is there something i didn't do right here? But the list2 is been populated

function ShoppingListService( ) {
              var service = this;

```
          service.shoppingList2 = [
          {
            name: "Milk",
            quantity: "2"
          },
          {
            name: "Donuts",
            quantity: "200"
          },
          {
            name: "Cookies",
            quantity: "300"
          },
           {
            name: "Musli",
            quantity: "10"
          },
          {
            name: "Chocolate",
            quantity: "5"
          }
        ];
```

This part is been populated onclick  but retuning empty object. i want the objects to move here on click but something is not complete and i can't figure it out

```
service.bought = [];


    service.remove = function(itemIndex){
        service.bought.push(service.shoppingList2.splice(itemIndex,1));

    }

    service.getItems = function(){
        return service.bought;
    };


}


})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You left out the quotation marks for the objects name definition in your list. Add quotation marks to each object definition, they need to be written as if they were in a JSON file.

```
 service.shoppingList2 = [
      {
       "name": "Milk",
        "quantity": "2"
      }
    ];
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: this makes no difference either


service.shoppingList2 = [
      {
       "name": "Milk",
        "quantity": "2"
      }
    ];